# Use Qt Dbus on Windows

Tags: windows, qt, dbus

I want to use Qt Dbus on Windows(Windows 10, Qt 5.10.1), I have read this post: [QtDbus is not working in Qt5.4.1 on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702421/qtdbus-is-not-working-in-qt5-4-1-on-windows-7?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

downloaded the library according to this link:
http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2014-December/019502.html

and added bin folder to $PATH, in my case, C:\Qt\dbus\64\bin, since there are both 32-bit and 64-bit versions in the zip file, I also add C:\Qt\dbus\32\bin to $PATH, started dbus daemon as following:
c:\Qt\dbus\64\bin>dbus-daemon.exe --config-file=..\etc\dbus-1\session.conf

However when I tried to run Qt dbus chat example, I still got: 
Starting C:\Qt\Examples\Qt-5.10.1\dbus\build-chat-Desktop_Qt_5_10_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\chat.exe...
Cannot connect to the D-Bus session bus.
Please check your system settings and try again.

C:/Qt/Examples/Qt-5.10.1/dbus/build-chat-Desktop_Qt_5_10_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug/debug/chat.exe exited with code 1

Anyone can help? I may give up using Qt Dbus on Windows and find another way for IPC for my project if this won't work. I used Qt Dbus on Linux quite a lot.

Comment: Have you verified that the Dbus daemon process is running and working?